# Protractor:How to remove extra space from string just like we use in java getText.trim()

Tags: javascript, protractor

How to remove extra space from string just like we use in `java getText.trim()` in **Protractor**,
**I used like this:**

```
var columnvalue=rows.get(9).getText();
var columnvalue1=columnvalue.trim();
```

***but i got error:***
`Object [object Object]` *has no method 'trim'*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Andreas' solution is basically correct. I'm just appending some additional info.

I'm not sure what you're using the trim for, but

1) if you're trying to put it into an assertion:

```
expect(rows.get(9).getText()).toMatch('\s*STRING_TO_MATCH\s*')
```

or simply

```
expect(rows.get(9).getText()).toContain('STRING_TO_MATCH')
```

2) If you want a promise that returns the trimmed value

```
var columnvalue=rows.get(9).getText();
var columnvalue1=columnvalue.then(function(text) {return text.trim();})
```

Comment: This answer is more helpful since this is probably what he wants to do :)

Comment: Thank you now its working fine,actually i want to store values in array for sorting.

Answer (score 6):

The `getText()` method returns a Promise object. You need to do like this to get the string:

```
rows.get(9).getText().then(function(text) {
  console.log(text.trim());
});
```

If you look at the error you got you will see that it's trying to access the method `trim()` of an object, not a string.

Comment: I don't know why I got downvoted but I'm pretty sure this is correct. :)

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted, but I upvoted it back to neutral =)

Answer (score 0):

With async/await you can resolve the promise like this and call `trim()` directly.

```
expect((await page.getElement().getText()).trim()).toBe('');
```