# Trimming protractor attribute value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, bdd

I am gathering values from a form to drop into an array that will compare against another array of values to ensure that the arrays match forming my test spec.

Here's how the two are matching and failing currently:

```
Expected [ '8', '{
     "Name": "JoeNew"
}', 'Chilli', 'Customer Group 2' ] to equal [ '8', '{"Name":"JoeNew"}', 'Chilli', 'Customer Group 2' ]
```

The value causing the trouble is a JSON field pulled from a textarea field. The first array's JSON needs to be trimmed to match that in the second array `{"Name":"JoeNew"}'`.

I am gathering the value this way:

```
browser.params.updatedValues.push(element(by.id(fieldName2)).getAttribute('value'));
```

This is the resolved with:

```
protractor.promise.all(browser.params.updatedValues).then(function (resolvedValues) {
    browser.params.updatedValues = resolvedValues;
    expect(browser.params.updatedValues).toEqual(browser.params.newValues);
});
```

===============

I have tried to pass the value to a function like so:

```
browser.params.updatedValues.push(trimResult(element(by.id(fieldName2)).getAttribute('value')));

function trimResult(toTrim) {
    return toTrim.trim();
};
```

But this informs me that trim is not a function. I have also attempted the following, similar to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576288/protractorhow-to-remove-extra-space-from-string-just-like-we-use-in-java-gettex):

```
console.log("Values is: " + element(by.id(fieldName2)).getAttribute('value').then(function(trim){return trim.trim();}));
```

Which gives me `Values is: Promise::30446 {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"}`.

Please help!

Comment: Does anyone have an answer that they might be able to share? Pleeeeeease?